# oh-my-zsh.sh not a valid file/directory but shouldn't it create itself when from zshrc?

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

I'm trying to set up oh my zsh to use the auto suggestion plug in. I'm having trouble why my oh-my-zsh.sh file is not being created. Ive followed all steps and both zsh and oh-my-zsh are installed properly but can't seem to find the problem in my zshrc file.

```
export PATH="/Users/someuser/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools":"/Users/someuser/Personal/Pokemon-Terminal/":$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:$PATH:Downloads/apache-maven-3.5.0/bin
export ZSH=/Users/someuser/.oh-my-zsh
export TERM=screen-256color

ZSH_THEME_RANDOM_CANDIDATES=(
"robbyrussell"
"agnoster"
"amuse"
"lamda"
"awesomepanda"
)

plugins=(sudo git history zsh-autosuggestions)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

alias gitconfig="atom ~/.gitconfig"
alias zshconfig="atom ~/.zshrc"
alias ohmyzsh="atom ~/.oh-my-zsh"
alias fucking='sudo'
alias pubkey='pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub'
alias stfu="osascript -e 'set volume output muted true'"

source ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/zsh-completions
source ~/.zsh/zsh-autosuggestions/zsh-autosuggestions.zsh

export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
```

When I open up a new terminal I get an error that these 2 lines are not a file or directory

```
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
source ~/.zsh/zsh-autosuggestions/zsh-autosuggestions.zsh
```

The only thing inside of /.oh-my-zsh is 'custom'. I figured it would all auto generate but clearly i'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oh-my-zsh didn't not install correctly and did not fill out ~/.zshrc like it was supposed to. Upon uninstalling and reinstallation the .zshrc file was pre-filled as expected.